# Wifi connection windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a pretty good wifi antenna for my laptop, so it sees a lot of wifi networks.
I have 2 problems.

1. The windows interface only shows about 6 or 7 networks. It won't show the whole list. And often the one I'm interested in is not showing. Is there a way to show all available networks?
2. To get around problem 1,I've been playing with the netsh command. I found a command to connect to a network, but it already has to be in your profile. Is there a way to connect to a new named network via the cmd line?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks